# Ubuntu 10.04 on 64bit

Tags: cpu, 64bit, x86

I need to download the 64bit version of Ubuntu 10.04,
I found this link http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/
and select this option:

> PC (Intel x86) desktop CD

But it is x86? And the other 64bit option just for AMD processor

Answer (score 3):

It's not just for *AMD*, it works for my Intel i5 processor as well, that was merely a naming convenience.

Also, consider the 12.04 version instead, as 10.04 is going to be obsolete.

Comment: i need this version 10.04 and my laptop is 64bit

Comment: @Hanaa i5 can be run in 64bit mode, I'm using it now, what's your processor model

Comment: my processor is intel i3 , is it work with ?

Comment: @Hanaa yes. And FYI, for the next time just try boot the cd, and if it's not supported, it won't boot at all.

Answer (score 0):

Today's processors are almost uniformly 64 bit. Intel copied the 64 bit architecture from AMD when their own 64 bit Itanic tanked. (Even my Intel Atom netbook is 64 bit). The one you should use is the AMD64 one, the x86 is 32 bits.